# joomla front end payment process different to back end test drive process

Tags: joomla, payment-processor

Using CiviCRM v4.7 under Joomla v3.5

Am developing a payment extension (type notify) which is all but working when I test the contribution page on the back end: user is transferred to goCardless site for completion of payment details and then returned to a success url.

But in the front end using the same contribution page from a Joomla menu item the behaviour is different:

- no choice is given for payment processor

From further research I notice the the table 'civicrm_contribution_page' shows associated payment processors ('payment_processor'). While I have checked 2 payment processors with id's 25, 26 (test), 27 and 28 (test) this field in the table 'civicrm_contribution_page' shows '2527'

Maybe this has something to do with it?